# NodeMCU - can't communicate at all via serial?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I just received my NodeMCU, I have installed the `CP210x` driver. It shows up as: `/dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART`

This is under `OSX 10.11.6`.

However, I cannot upload any sketch via Arduino (I have installed the ESP community libraries). I cannot even get a response using esptool, for example if I try:

```
esptool.py -p /dev/tty.SLAB_USBtoUART -b 9600 read_flash_status
```

Then I just get "Connecting..." and nothing else happens. I am wondering if it is stuck in flash mode maybe? I don't know how to check this though or how to get it out if so. Or have I just been sold a bad device? Is there any way I can tell? I have tried two USB cables but I am not also powering the board with an external power supply. Could this be the issue?

Any advice would be great, I have plenty of experience with Arduino but completely new to the ESP.

Comment: What kind of devkit is it? I guess you _are_ using USB data cables (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/140225/118337)? My devices always show up under two different device names on macOS, maybe try the second one as well...

Comment: Yes they are data cables and it does show up when I plug it in vs unplugged. It's when I try to communicate with it that things don't work. It was sold as NodeMCU Lua ESP8266 Development Board ESP12.

Comment: Is it one of them: https://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/? Have you gone through https://github.com/espressif/esptool/#troubleshooting already?